# How to loop an addition and substraction on a base of 3 in query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simpple Slider with 3 slides. Now everything works, but if I press more than 3 times in one direction I get "false" numbers. Mathemathically they are right, but Im aiming for this scenario:

If i click 4 times the button for previous slide, the counter of my numbers should be again 3, not -1. Any way to archive this?

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    
  var current =  $('.slider_number').data("hasso");
  var total = $('.slider_number').data("total")

  $('.slider_next').click(function(){
  ++current;
  console.log(current)
  $(".slider_number").text(current)
});
  $('.slider_prev').click(function(){
  --current;
  console.log(current)
}                                     
);
 });
```

Comment: Create a reset function where it updates your count to the correct index. You would need to check if the count is at first position or last position and update your index accordingly. If you click next and your count is already at last position, you would update the count to 0 and if you clicked on prev slide when you are already at the first slide, you want to update the count to total number of slide - 1 assuming 0 index

Comment: For prev, when current == 0, current = current + total. I would hope you can figure out the next with the same kind of logic. This is assuming 1 based index which I think is what you have. 3 slides, clicked 4th time you get -1 so must be 1 based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the circular index formula `(i % n + n) % n` where `n` is the length of the array (4 in your case).

use:

```
current = (current+1 % total + total) % total;
```

to move forward;

and

```
current = (current-1 % total + total) % total;
```

to move backwards.

`current` will always be a valid index.

Comment: Not it works, but only for the one side. The other one is giving me random numbers it seems

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q01vx42g/

Comment: @HasanKawaaiPikachu It doesn't work because you've changed the formula. this works just fine https://jsfiddle.net/nxdq2zL1/10